# How to place an object at specific location in ARcore?

Tags: arcore

I am trying to **place an object at specific location without tapping**, Is there any direct method to place an object at **real world location.**

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you could do this.

1. Search flat surface.
   2.**override onUpdate** method.
2. loop through trackables and than your model has been projected without tapping.

   i just give you an idea, how onUpdate method is look like, this is pseudo code

   ```
      frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
       if (frame != null) {
           //get the trackables 
           Iterator<Plane> var3 = frame.getUpdatedTrackables(Plane.class).iterator();
           while (var3.hasNext()) {
               Plane plane = var3.next();

               //If a plane has been detected & is being tracked by ARCore
               if (plane.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {

                   //Hide the plane discovery helper animation
                   arFragment.getPlaneDiscoveryController().hide();


                   //Get all added anchors to the frame
                   Iterator<Anchor> iterableAnchor = frame.getUpdatedAnchors().iterator();

                   //place the first object only if no previous anchors were added
                   if (!iterableAnchor.hasNext()) {
                       //Perform a hit test at the center of the screen to place an object without tapping
                       List<HitResult> hitTest = frame.hitTest(getScreenVector3().x, getScreenVector3().y);

                       //iterate through all hits
                       Iterator<HitResult> hitTestIterator = hitTest.iterator();
                       while (hitTestIterator.hasNext()) {
                           HitResult hitResult = hitTestIterator.next();

                           //Create an anchor at the plane hit

                               Anchor modelAnchor = plane.createAnchor(hitResult.getHitPose());

                               //Attach a node to this anchor with the scene as the parent
                               anchorNode = new AnchorNode(modelAnchor);
                               anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());

                               **create a new TranformableNode that will carry our model**
                               }


                       }
                   }
               }
           }

       }
   ```

Comment: Hey, thanks @Bilz I will definitely try this. thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: please give me feedback if it is working for you @Md.Shahim

Comment: frame.hitTest(getScreenVector3().x, getScreenVector3().y); this method is not available Hitresults Library , please clear getScreenVector3 child of which superclass ?

Comment: both these method are custom created method.

Comment: can you please share if possible ?

Comment: private Vector3 getScreenVector3() {

        View vw = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        Vector3 vec = new Vector3(vw.getWidth() / 2f, vw.getHeight() / 2f, 0f);
        return vec;
    }
you can use this code it return x and y.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the node directly to the scene:

```
node.localPosition = Vector3(x, y, z)
arSceneView.scene.addChild(node)
```